# N Queens: possible arrangements on 8x8 board

Tags: combinations, chessboard

I am studying the [$N$-Queens problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle) and have found the [following statement](https://www.quora.com/What-is-best-average-and-worst-case-in-case-of-N-Queen-Problem)

> Now number of possible arrangements of $N$ Queens on $N \times N$ chessboard is
>   $N!$, given you are skipping row or column, already having a queen
>   placed. So average and worst case complexity of the solution is $O(N!)$
>   (since, you are checking all the possible solutions i.e. $N^N$
>   arrangements). The best case occurs if you find your solution before
>   exploiting all possible arrangements. This depends on your
>   implementation.
>
> And if you need all the possible solutions, the best, average and
>   worst-case complexity remains $O(N!)$

(**Note**: none of the other answers (or links on them) on the link above help in my understanding)

I don't understand this at all.

Surely the total number of possible arrangements (*not the total number of solutions*) for the $8$ Queens - assuming we have an 8x8 board (hence $N=8$) - will be

$64\cdot 63\cdot 62\cdot 61\cdot 60\cdot 59\cdot 58\cdot 57$

...based on what I learned from a similar problem ([number of seating arrangements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eoxbgUIYhHo)), which gives me a far, far greater value than $N^N$???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quote you have posted is making use of the fact that in the $N$-queens problem none of the queens is allowed to be threatening any of the others, so there must be exactly $1$ queen in each column (otherwise the queens in the same column would threaten each other). So if we want find solutions to the $N$-queens problem we need only consider potential solutions with $1$ queen per column. For each column choose a row in which to place a queen, giving us $N^N$ arrangements to check.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  1) Without this 1 Queen per column constraint, I would be correct with the number of combinations being 64*63*...57, right?  2) Can you please show how we can get $N^N$ by assuming there will only be one Queen per column?

Comment: @Wad to (1), yes, in general there are $\frac{(N^2)!}{(N^2 - N)!}$ ways to place $N$ markers on an $N\times N$ board with no restrictions. To (2) since we need to place $N$ queens there must be exactly one queen per column. In the first column choose one of $N$ squares to place a queen, similarly for each of the remaining $N - 1$ columns we have a choice of $N$ squares. So there are $N^N$ possible ways to do this.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't understand how $N^N$ is obtained; this is not a strong point of mine.  Could you (possibly diagrammatically) explain this deduction further, please?

Comment: Let's consider $n = 3$. We want to place 3 queens, one in each column. First place a queen in column a, there are 3 ways to do this. Next in column b, again 3 ways to do this, so $3\cdot 3 = 9$ total ways we could have placed our queens so far. Finally, choose one of the 3 positions in column c to place a queen. So all together there are $3^3 = 27$ ways we could have done this. This generalizes directly to $N$, we'll just place $N$ queens and have $N$ choices at each step, so $N^N$ possible ways to place them.